# iOS - Retina display assets not working?

Tags: ios, retina-display

I'm running my app on an iPhone 4, and the navigation bar and all my labels are very blurry (Non-retina). Most blurry ui elements are iOS default UIs.

When I run other applications on my phone they look a lot nicer, and you can easily see the difference.

Is there any project setting that I need to change in order to get higher quality Assets to be used in my app?

**EDIT:**

I don't care about my own assets, What I care about right now is the **DEFAULT UI ELEMENTS IN IOS**

**EDIT:**

I have added a shadow to my main UINavigationController, In order to improve performance while animating the shadows, i set ShouldRasterize to YES, removing this line of xode fixes the problem

```
[self.navigationController.view.layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
```

Comment: Add the @2x suffix to your images (ex. Icon.png 57x57 & Icon@2x.png 114x114)

Comment: Can you guarantee it's the software and not your eyes?

Comment: Yes the difference is very clear, I also had others confirm it

Comment: Is everything updated to the latest version? (Mac, Xcode, iPhone, etc.)

Comment: Not sure; this has always worked seamlessly for me. Maybe you need to link against a newer version of UIKit for it to work? What version of Xcode, and what SDK are you compiling the app with?

Comment: Does this happen if you create a new project?

Comment: Check out my answer. I am pretty certain its your problem given your situation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you set Should Rasterize you have to remember to set your rasterization scale.

```
[self.view.layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
[self.view.layer setRasterizationScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
```

You have to remember that rasterizing converts the layer to a simple bitmap thats stored in memory to save cpu cycles during complex animations. However if you're on a Retina device you need to make sure you save it at double the scale since the screen has 4 times the pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made the doubled sized imaged with the @2x suffix to it?

e.g. 
navBarBackground.png & navBarBackground@2x.png (last one is double the size of the first one)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW16

Comment: I think his question is more about UIKit members, instead of external images.

Comment: Yet, the status bar and all other native desings are automatically on retina if the device is a retina device, regardless of the app having retina support or not.

Comment: I don't use any custom images, the whole app is using default UI Elements

Comment: Ok, my next suggestion is for you to check if you are building for iOS5, 4, 3 ect. However, this should not make any difference. Also... upload a screenshot of you result.

Comment: My Base SDK is 5.1, and my iPhone is running 5.1 as well.